# Is it possible to have multiple installation of Java on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, java, avast

I have Avast that is telling me I need to update 2 out of 3 instances of Java :

[image: see externalimage here]

How is that possible ? Knowing that I run Eclipse and that I have frequent "stale" problem with it... Is it running a self instance of Java, I don't think so.

If anyone as an idea how to deal with that ?

Comment: I guess eclipse would have issues if all you have is the JRE(only enough to run java programs) and not the SDK/JDK(the stuff to compile and run them). Eclipse no doubt would just point to the SDK/JDK, whichever you point it to. If they're all in different directories there's no clash.

Comment: I use Eclipse PDT , for PHP programming, no java at all, so I guess I don't need the SDK. What's your though ?

Comment: you can haev multiple java installations. you should include exactly what error you're getting.

Comment: Actually, I don't have errors. Just frequent / long stale / rotating wait icon with grayed Eclipse window. Eventually it returns to normal. Wonder if it's due to those several installations of java. Anyway, I've uninstalled every Java instance. Installed the 64bit JRE from java.com.

Note that I use Eclipse 64bit.

Set the Windows Path to point to the 64bit version of Java. Cross fingers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entirely possible and normal, if you have specific needs for multiple JVMs.  Due to running legacy software, I have specific versions of 1.5, 1.6, and 1.7 on my development machine, and two versions on one production machine.

What you're probably asking though, is why didn't upgrading one upgrade the others?  Well, quite often software installs will include the JRE version they were tested on, and store them in a subfolder of the application directory.

I would recommend not worrying much about outdated JVMs that are in the latter situation.  The ones you should be most concerned with are the JVMs accessed by your browser plugins, since they expose you to already-patched and even unknown vulnerabilities (for now, turn off Java in browsers, and maybe forever, heh).

You CAN try upgrading the various JVMs and test whether those applications still work, but there's probably no reason to do so, other than performance (for example 1.7 smokes 1.5 in speed, about 2:1).